# Lead cannot be converted if owner is Queue

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I have validation rule where lead cannot be converted if owner is Queue, i tried different sets of validation rules but none of them works, any help is appreciated

1) AND(
     IsConverted = TRUE,
     Owner:Queue.Id = '00G400000015Xyi'
     )

2)  AND(
     IsConverted = TRUE,
     ISBLANK(Owner:Queue.Id) 
    )

```
3) AND(
 IsConverted = TRUE,
 (CONTAINS(OwnerId,"00G"))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if validation rules are enforced :

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000176187&language=en_US

Read more here : 
http://simplysfdc.blogspot.com/2013/12/salesforce-lead-conversion-validation.html

**Update:**

Update the formula to

```
AND( 
IsConverted, 
PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) = "Queue_ID" 
)
```

If you are expecting to see the validation error show up on the page where the convert button is, as far as I know the lead conversion page validates the validation rule and not the lead page where you press the convert button.

[image]

Comment: Yes they are enabled

Comment: @Admin_BA updated the answer.

Comment: I was expecting on the conversion page but i don't get any error, no matter who owns the lead the conversion is taking place, anything wrong with my syntax?

Comment: @Admin_BA nope i dont see any issue, i have used your exact formula for my validation. Try with ownerId and see if the validation are firing, if they do fire it has to do something with queue

Comment: Have you used Queue Id? I used owner id and it works but for queue it doesn't,  what is the issue? is there any workaround?

Comment: Dang should have realized that the owner changes on convert. check if priorvalue(ownerID) = "QueueId", adding this to the validation worked for me with queue too.

Comment: Great it worked, one question though since we have many queues do i need to enter all queues or is there any other trick? this is what iam using now AND( IsConverted = TRUE, 
         priorvalue(OwnerId) = '00G40000001LiCB'
       )

Comment: do you want the lead convert to fail for all the lead queues, if so use contains(priorvalue(ownerId),"OOG"). else you can use custom setting, which i need to explore since list custom settings are not allowed in validation rules.