# Validation rule to not allow the conversion of a lead with an specific owner id

Tags: leads, lead-conversion, conversion, owner, lead-assignment

I want to avoid the conversion of a lead if its owner id is equal to 0050O000009PQCKCKQA4.

In Setup/Lead Settings I have activated the option "Require Validation for Converted Leads".

This is the validation rule:

AND(
IsConverted,
OwnerId = '0050O000009PQCKQA4'
)

However, it still allows me to convert the lead despite having this owner id.

Can you tell me why it does not work?

Thank you very much for your help.

Mónica Martínez

Comment: you can use debug logs to see how your Validation rules are executing. Also, avoid use of IDs in VRs - they are not self-documenting. I'd create a formula field `Is Owner PreventedFrom Conversion?` - see this [helpful post on polymorphic Owner formulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/cross-object-owner-fields-a-powerful-new-formula-option)

Comment: Have you looked at this? [Validation rule on lead conversion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266164/validation-rule-on-lead-conversion-preventing-specific-users-ownership-of-recor), [Restrict converting lead is user is not owner](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49990/restrict-converting-lead-is-user-is-not-owner), and [Lead cannot be converted if owner is Queue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50178/lead-cannot-be-converted-if-owner-is-queue)

Answer (score 0):

Validation rules require 15-character IDs, they do not work with 18-character IDs.

Comment: Thank you, now is working

Answer (score -2):

there is little modification in your validation rule:-
AND(
ISCHANGED(IsConverted),
IsConverted,
Owner.Id = '00LXXXXXXXXXXXX'
)
IsConvereted is the field.
Please let me know if you have any doubt! Happy to help.

Comment: Using the lookup field on an object (e.g. `OwnerId`) is preferable to using the Id field on the related record (e.g. `Owner.Id`). Also, I'm not sure if including `isConverted` on its own would make any difference in detecting when a Lead is being converted. This is an example of something you should try in your own org first to make sure it works _before_ posting it as an answer.

Comment: Also, an Id starting with `00L` (the Id prefix for Leads) will _never_ match an OwnerId (which can have either a Group, prefix `00G`, or a User, prefix `005`).